# adding metadata to layer in Illustrator

Tags: metadata, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to add metadata to a layer in Adobe Illustrator? I'm looking to pull layer data (description, etc.) into a database from layer info, after saving out as an SVG. I want to see if there is a cleaner method than adding an arbitrary text box to read separately from the actual object the metadata describes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Illustrator Scripting Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/illustrator_scripting_reference_javascript_cs5.pdf), there's no metadata you can associate with a `Layer` object.

However, the `Document` object has a field for [XMP Metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform). If you can shoehorn your metadata in there, that could be useful. (I'm not sure if that survives export to SVG, though.)

Otherwise, I think you're stuck doing something hacky, like putting the metadata into text objects. Is your objection to text boxes just that it seems inelegant? Or is it causing specific problems or drawbacks? If it's the latter, we might be able to help you come up with a better hack if you give more details about why text boxes are problematic for you.